# php mysql error, complaining about insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert

The error I get is

> Error No: 0 - MySQL error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1

```
Query:
#0 {main}
```

The code is as follows

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO events (start_date, end_date, duration, typedesc, inorout, amount, desc) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

I cannot, for the life of me, see the error.  I have almost the identical code in another script that works fine.  I've checked, double checked, and triple checked the table name, and column names.  Everything looks ok to me.

Any thoughts on where to begin now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`desc`** is a [**`reserved keyword`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) in **`MySQL`**, you need to wrap it in backticks.

Like this...

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `events` (`start_date`, `end_date`, `duration`, `typedesc`, `inorout`, `amount`, `desc`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: Just add backticks to every column name and you are on the safe side.

Comment: @HerrSerker, Yeah i was doing that when you were commenting. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that was it!  Wow, thanks guys. I'll accept in 9 minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` is a reserved MySql keyword used afrer `ORDER BY fieldname` to perform a descending sort.

Try this:

> INSERT INTO events (`start_date`, `end_date`, `duration`, `typedesc`, `inorout`, `amount`, `desc`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran, I was writing my answer while you posted... Sorry!

Comment: What's even funnier is that desc was my shorthand 'description' and totally forgot about it being the shorthand for descending on the orderby.  Sometimes our brains just block stuff out based on our thinking about the problem at hand.